# Overriding inherited generic method in managed C++/CLI

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I wrote the code in C# and it works fine:

```
public interface IBase<T>
{
}

public abstract class BaseImpl<T> : IBase<T> 
{
    public abstract T2 CreateInstance<T2>();
}

public class InstanceX : BaseImpl<string>
{
    public override T2 CreateInstance<T2>() 
    {
        return default(T2); 
    }
}

public class TestInstanceX
{
    void TestIt() 
    {
        InstanceX mProvX = new InstanceX();
        string str1 = mProvX.CreateInstance<String>();
    }
}
```

I have tried to move it to managed c++:

```
generic <typename T>
public ref class BaseImpl abstract: IBase<T> 
{
public:

    generic <typename T2>
    virtual T2 CreateInstance() abstract;

};

public ref class InstanceX : BaseImpl<String^>
{
public:
    generic <typename T2>
    virtual T2 CreateInstance() override
    {
        return (T2)(Object^) nullptr; 
    }
};

public ref class TestInstanceX
{
    void TestIt() 
    {
        InstanceX^ mProvX = gcnew InstanceX();
        String^ str1 = mProvX->CreateInstance<String^>();
    }
};
```

In managed C++ I get the compiler error:

> Test.h: error C229: 'InstanceX' : cannot instantiate abstract class
>            due to following members:
>            'T2 BaseImpl::CreateInstance(void)' : is abstract
>            with
>            [
>                T=System::String ^
>            ]
>
> Test.h: see declaration of 'BaseImpl::CreateInstance'
>            with
>            [
>                T=System::String ^
>            ]

How must be overridden (implemented) the "CreateInstance" function in the InstanceX class in managed C++?

Answer (score 0):

This strikes me as a possible bug in the C++/CLI compiler. It seems that if the base class and the subclass have different generic types (`T` vs. no longer generic), and the method being overridden has a different generic type (`T2`), then it doesn't realize that the second generic type (`T2`) is actually the same.

To work around this, I would create a dummy intermediate class, which is still generic on type `T`. Implement the `T2` generic method there, and then inherit InstanceX from that.

Here's my test program.

Also, please note the implementation of CreateInstance: The C++/CLI equivalent to C#'s `default(T)` is `T()`. Casting `nullptr` to `Object^` then to `T2` results in a NullReferenceException when `T2` is a value type, such as `int`.

```
generic<typename T>
public interface class IBase
{
};

generic <typename T>
public ref class BaseImpl abstract: IBase<T>
{
public:
    generic <typename T2>
    virtual T2 CreateInstance() abstract;
};

generic <typename T>
public ref class IntermediateJustForOverriding : BaseImpl<T>
{
public:
    generic <typename T2>
    virtual T2 CreateInstance() override
    {
        return T2();
    }
};

public ref class InstanceX : IntermediateJustForOverriding<String^>
{
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    InstanceX^ mProvX = gcnew InstanceX();
    String^ str1 = mProvX->CreateInstance<String^>();

    Debug::WriteLine(str1);
    Debug::WriteLine(str1 == nullptr);
    Debug::WriteLine(mProvX->CreateInstance<int>());
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
True
0
```

Comment: And how can be overridden the function CreateInstance in the class InstanceX?  
I need in InstanceX the supporting for different types:  
IType1 t1 = mProvX->CreateInstance<IType1>();  
IType2 t2 = mProvX->CreateInstance<IType2>();  
etc.

Comment: You would implement whatever you needed for CreateInstance in the intermediate class. Instead of `IntermediateJustForOverriding`, perhaps a better name would be `ParentOfInstanceXAndInstanceXOnlyJustToWorkAroundACompilerIssue`. You would never refer to that class other than in `InstanceX`'s declaration.